# Computer telling me that files don't exist when they do

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

In the following code, I find two folders that match a certain name, and then try to list out the files within those directories. However, it tells me there is no such directory, when there is (see below demonstration)

There's probably plenty of solutions, I just don't even know how to describe the problem or how to start googling. I've gone on some posts but either the solutions don't work or I'm too stupid to implement them correctly.

```
D-XXX-XX-XXX-XXX:renameFoldersProject oppeasnt$ for i in "$(find ./temp -name "Bob, Emma" -type d)"; do (echo "$i";) done
./temp/2019/Bob, Emma
./temp/2020/Bob, Emma
D-XXX-XX-XXX-XXX:renameFoldersProject oppeasnt$ for i in "$(find ./temp -name "Bob, Emma" -type d)"; do (ls "$i";) done
ls: ./temp/2019/Bob, Emma
./temp/2020/Bob, Emma: No such file or directory
D-XXX-XX-XXX-XXX:renameFoldersProject oppeasnt$ ls "./temp/2019/Bob, Emma"
IPPE_Comm_Calc_Received_1.pdf   IPPE_Comm_Calc_Received_2.pdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put quotes around the command substitution, then you get one giant token; the entire output of the command is stuffed into `var`, resulting in a single iteration of the loop

```
$ for x in "a b c d"; do echo "<$x>"; done
<a b c d>

$ for x in a b c d; do echo "<$x>"; done
<a>
<b>
<c>
<d>
```

Since the paths you're scanning have spaces, the approach is not workable.  Investigate the `-exec` predicate of `find`, or the use of a `while read ...` shell loop, or else the use a more capable scripting language.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Could you provide an example? I don't have that many tools available to me and I'm definitely not an expert, but I need to fix this issue pretty quickly.

Comment: For instance, the`while read` loop approach. Start with this: `find /temp -name "Bob, Emma" | while read path ; do ls -l "$path" ; done`.  The `read` command respects lines; if `find` outputs `a b c` as a line, then `path` gets `a b c`.